# How to create this animated arrow?

Tags: c++, windows, windows-7

I have just installed a program on my pc and after that, an animated arrow is appeared on the screen showing me a new element on the bar:

[image]

How can I create this animated arrow ? What API do I have to use ?

Comment: 236 questions asked, 60% accept, just sayin'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It can be made with a window that has a custom shape.  One of my colleagues documented how to do this in .NET here:

http://www.atalasoft.com/cs/blogs/jake/archive/2008/05/09/beauty-is-only-skin-deep-skinning-your-winforms-application.aspx

http://www.atalasoft.com/cs/blogs/jake/archive/2008/05/19/beauty-is-only-skin-deep-part-deux-if-it-looks-like-a-duck-it-might-be-a-winform.aspx

The same thing can be done in C++ by following the technique

Answer (score 1):

I'm not aware that such a capability is exposed in an API. I expect the app draws it directly which it is of course perfectly entitled to do.

Comment: Are you sure that the OS draws the arrow? I have never seen it, so I doubt that. I would guess that the newly installed program itself drew the arrow (just so that the user knows it is the most awesome program ever created by mankind, to use the words of Chen).

Comment: @Andreas Er, I misread the question. I thought OP had freshly installed the OS. I've edited the answer. Like the Raymond reference!